# How to add a column to a python dataframe, that is a string manipulation of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

There is a column named `'country'` and I want a column that is `'abc'` <= the first two chars of `'country'`.

In pseudocode:

```
df['abc'] = df['country'][0:2]
```

Of course this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
df['abc'] = df['country'].str[:2]
```